# Persistent fruit on crabapple tree

Tags: crabapples

Crabapple tree never dropped last year’s apples. The branches are loaded in spring. Should I remove the apples?

Comment: Pictures please, crabapples can be small or large and trees can usually bear the load but it depends on how it has been pruned.  Please show us a picture or two

Comment: Usually, birds eat the fruit all winter. I've used crabapples 1:3 with sweet apples in applesauce -- and sugar or maple syrup.